# How to create animation dynamically and add it to overridePendingTransition

Tags: android, android-animation

I want to know how to add animations that are created dynamically in Java to overridePendingTransition.

I created a custom animation in Java.

```
Animation anim = new ScaleAnimation(....);
```

Now I want to add this animation to overridePendingTransition.

```
overridePendingTransition(anim, anim);
```

But I get an error. It says I need to have an int. 
I know I can use R.anim.scaleanim created from xml too. But I want to create the animation dynamically in Java so that the pivotX and pivotY values are changed in code.

Please help me. Thank you!